# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I can't save changes and when I tried to see what going wrong I found that there is a problem on the index.php under wp admin folder

x.send("") gives an error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var compressionNonce = "8023f35fe4";
  var testCompression = {
    get: function(test) {
      var x;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        x = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        try {
          x = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        } catch (e) {
          try {
            x = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
          } catch (e) {};
        }
      }

      if (x) {
        x.onreadystatechange = function() {
          var r, h;
          if (x.readyState == 4) {
            r = x.responseText.substr(0, 18);
            h = x.getResponseHeader('Content-Encoding');
            testCompression.check(r, h, test);
          }
        };

        x.open('GET', ajaxurl + '?action=wp-compression-test&test=' + test + '&_ajax_nonce=' + compressionNonce + '&' + (new Date()).getTime(), true); **
        * x.send(''); ** *
      }
    },

    check: function(r, h, test) {
      if (!r && !test)
        this.get(1);

      if (1 == test) {
        if (h && (h.match(/deflate/i) || h.match(/gzip/i)))
          this.get('no');
        else
          this.get(2);

        return;
      }

      if (2 == test) {
        if ('"wpCompressionTest' == r)
          this.get('yes');
        else
          this.get('no');
      }
    }
  };
  testCompression.check();
</script>
```

Comment: What kind of changes are you trying to save. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: ***x.send('');***, what is the purpose of stars before and after

Comment: for example if I try to customize the theme I can't save the changes

Comment: @charankumar just to show that the problem is there

Answer (score 0):

I find that you can often not save changes to a ***live*** theme through WP console.
It can be done on the terminal or via file edit but often not through /wp-admin/network/theme-editor.php

It spins its wheels for a while but never saves.
My work around if I only have access to the WP admin and not a terminal is to swap the live theme to something else for a few mins while I make the code update.